# How to compute the integral of a renewal process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $\{S_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a renewal process (with the convention $S_0\equiv 0$) with $\mathbb E[S_1]<\infty$ and $S_1$ absolutely continuous with density $f$. Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be the associated counting process. I want to compute $$K(t):=\int_0^t N(s)\ \mathsf ds$$ but am not sure how to proceed for an arbitrary $f$.

Let's consider the Poisson process, i.e. $f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ where $\lambda>0$. Then as $N(t)\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda t)$, we have $$\mathbb P(K(t)=0)=\mathbb P(S_1>t)=e^{-\lambda t} $$ and on $\{S_1\leqslant t\}$,
\begin{align}
K(t) &= \int_0^t N(s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= N(t)(t-S_{N(t)})+\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)-1} N(S_i)(S_{i+1}-S_{i})\\
&= N(t)(t-S_{N(t)})+\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)-1} i(S_{i+1}-S_i).
\end{align}
The memoryless property yields that $t-S_{N(t)}\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$, so conditioning on $N(t)$, we find that
\begin{align}
f_{K(t)\mathsf 1_{\{K(t)>0\}}\mid N(t)=n}(x) = \frac{(\lambda x)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2-1}}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2-1\right)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda x},
\end{align}
so that $K(t)$ has a mixture Erlang distribution, with density 
\begin{align}
f_{K(t)}(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{K(t)\mid N(t)=n}(x)\mathbb P(N(t)=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda x)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2-1}}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2-1\right)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
That sum does not appear to have a closed form, so I'm not sure if there's an error in my computations or if it's best to consider Laplace transforms here.

Comment: There is a mistake in the computation of the conditional density (can't tell where exactly). Obviously, given $N(t) = n$, $K(t) \le tn$. Slightly less obviously, the conditional distribution is independent of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, just a correction for the case of Poisson process.

Clearly, given $N(t) = n$, 
$$
K(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n (t-\tau_k),
$$
where $\tau_k$ is the $k$th jump time. It is well known that, given $N(t) = n$, the jump times $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n$ are distributed as order statistics $U_{(1)},\dots, U_{(n)}$ of an iid $U[0,t]$ sample $U_1,\dots,U_n$. Thus,
$$
K(t)  \overset{d}= \sum_{k=1}^n (t-U_{(k)}) = \sum_{k=1}^n (t-U_{k}) \overset{d}= \sum_{k=1}^n U_{k}.
$$
Therefore, the characteristic function of $K(t)$ in this case is 
$$
\varphi_{K(t)}(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{ist}-1}{ist}\right)^n\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda t} = \exp\left\{\lambda t\left(\frac{e^{ist}-1}{ist}-1\right)\right\}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. When I have time I will try to generalize this result for an arbitrary renewal process.

Comment: @Math1000, the argument is really ad hoc, so I doubt it can be generalized. I suggest looking at the particular distributions: Pareto, gamma. This may provide a hint how this would like in a general case.